# UI5 oData and two depended selection

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to create two dynamic selection lists using SAPUI5 and XML as developing paradigm for views.

Here is example of my oData model:

1. **/EmployeeSet** - return two entities:

   - Pernr = '00000001'
   - Pernr = '00000002'
2. **/EmployeeSet('00000001')** - return one entity:

   - Pernr ='00000001' Name = 'Jacob'
3. **/EmployeeSet('00000002')** - return one entity:

   - Pernr ='00000002' Name = 'Matthew'
4. **/EmployeeSet('00000001')/KidsListSet** - returns two entities:

   - PernrKid = '00000010' Name = 'Sophia'
   - PernrKid = '00000011' Name = 'James'.
5. **/EmployeeSet('00000002')/KidsListSet** - returns three entities

   - PernrKid = '00000020' Name = 'Alexander'
   - PernrKid = '00000021' Name = 'Zoe'
   - PernrKid = '00000022' Name = 'Oliver'

Select1 is working as expected, default value is there and on click action I can see two values.

**Two selects:**

```
<Select id="select1" width="100%" items="{ path: '/EmployeeSet' } change="handleSelect1">
<core:Item key="{Pernr}" text="{Name}" />
</Select>

<Select id="select2" width="100%" items="{ path: '/KidsListSet' }>
<core:Item key="{PernrKid}" text="{Name}" />
</Select>
```

**Code for handleAssigment function:**

```
handleAssigments : function(evt){
  var context = evt.getParameter("selectedItem").getBindingContext();
  var Path = context.getPath() + '/KidsListSet';
  var select2 = this.getView().byId("select2");

return select2.bindAggregation("items", Path, new sap.ui.core.Item({ key : "{PernrKid}", text : "{Name}" }));
},
```

When I change value in select1, select2 is updated and I see two or three entries (based on first selection)

However I have few questions:

1. How can I pre-populate default value for select2 (e.g. PernrKid = '00000010' Name = 'Sophia')
2. Maybe it's possible to do data binding without creating a new select Item in the view controller?

Thanks!

**Updated: 06/02/2014**

How I set oData model:

```
 // create root view
        var oView = sap.ui.view({
            id: "app",
            viewName: "view.App",
            type: "JS",
            viewData: { component : this }
        });


        // Load oData Model
        var sServiceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/YKIDS/";
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true, "", "");

        oView.setModel(oModel);
```

...

V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better to show placeholders or blank in the Selects if they have not been selected, showing actual values may mislead users into thinking they are set?

Alternatively, I am not sure how you would do it in the view, but you could listen on select1's binding onInit of the controller and update select2 from the first row of the bindings of select1

```
onInit: function(){    
var oSelect1 = this.getView().byId("select1");
var oBinding = oSelect1.getBinding("items");

var handler = function(oEvent) {

    //release the handler
    oBinding.detachDataReceived(handler);

    //get the first row of select1
    var aContexts = oEvent.oSource.getContexts();
    var row1 = aContexts[0];

    //get path to first rows kid list
    var Path = row1.getPath() + '/KidsListSet';

    //put values for first rows path into model either via select2 or the model
    eg  oModel.bindList(path)
    or select2.bindAggregation("items", Path ....

};
... set up model
var oModel = new ....

//attach handler
oBinding.attachDataReceived(handler);
```

Comment: Hi Jasper, oBinding is undefined, looks like my view binding is not available during initialization of controller. Any ideas?

Comment: @earny try moving the model up the top and see if that helps

Comment: oModel in defined in Component.js, but I'm not able to getBinding onInit.

Comment: Bindings are not yet established in onInit. Views are created already though (but not rendered yet meaning you won't find your view in the DOM at this point). Find more about controllers lifecycle hooks here: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/MVC.html

Comment: this what I thought as well. @cschuff, where I can access data binding in my view controller?

Comment: Bindings are established in onBeforeRendering. The docs are saying that this function is not called before the first rendering but experience shows that this is not true. Anyways: Be aware that this function will be called repeatedly before every rerendering.

Comment: You could pre-populate an item by using the `sap.m.Select` functions `setSelectedKey` or `setSelectedItemId`.

Comment: doh @cschuff is right oninit is too early, if you want to avoid setting a key you could create the binding for select1 manually oninit